# Compounds forming between silicon gallium and nitrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

What are the possible compounds that can form between silicon, gallium and nitrogen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is *de facto* a list-question.

Answer (score 1):

The ASM Alloy Phase Diagram Database ([ASM Database](http://www1.asminternational.org/asmenterprise/apd/default.aspx) if your institution has access) shows GaN and Si$_{3}$N$_{4}$ as the only compounds in that system. Standard binary alloy references agree. No ternary compounds are listed. Given the difference in crystal structures between all end members and the two nitride phases, mutual solubility of any two phases seems unlikely (little to none exists in the binaries, even Ga in Si has a pretty low solubility).

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation seems to be reasonable, but I have seen papers discussing the formation of $SiGaN_{3}$ compound [1]. Can you please comment on that?

[1] T. Markurt et al. Phys. Rev. Lett. 110, 036103 (2013)

Comment: There calculation is for a surface reconstruction, not a bulk phase. The free surface changes the free energy, leading to, for example, dimers being formed on Si (100) surface. This is not a bulk thermodynamic phase, so will not show up on binary or ternary (or higher) diagrams.

Comment: As a side note: silicon tetrazide is known, aluminium azide is known, I guess gallium azide should form as well.